# Display HTML List like an organizational chart

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble producing the correct CSS for my situation. Given the following list:

```
<ul>
    <li>Charlie
        <ul>
            <li>Tim
                <ul>
                    <li>Chris</li>
                    <li>Mort</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Julia
                <ul>
                    <li>Alice</li>
                    <li>Akuma</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to create a layout in CSS like this:
[image]

(I don't need the lines connecting them, but the layout of the boxes)

**Edit:**

CSS:

```
ul {
    width:100%;
    float:left;
}
ul li {
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    float:left
}
```

Then the other `ul li ul li`'s start to get confusing.

Comment: If jQuery is an option, it looks like people have created a few plugins for this: https://github.com/caprica/jquery-orgchart  https://github.com/wesnolte/jOrgChart

Comment: _"Is is possible"_? Sure. With CSS you're virtually unlimited. Worst case absolute positioning would solve the problem, however you seem to have left out what you've tried.

Comment: @JoshC That is what I am asking for and looking to write. I don't have anything usable so I am asking the question

Comment: @user1886419 We will help, but we don't do all the work. We like to see that an attempt has been made.

Comment: I am not sure but below link maybe useful (http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/css3-family-tree) to view code you may click on "View Code" button or Walkthrough would be better option